# What's the order of destruction of function parameters and return values?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In the following code:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    void Func();
    ~Foo();
};

Foo GetFoo(Foo foo);
```

The function `GetFoo` accepts a parameter `foo` by value and returns a `Foo` object. If we call `GetFoo` by this way:

```cpp
Foo f;
GetFoo(f).Func();
```

Will the parameter `foo` or the return value object destruct first according to the C++ standard?

---

C++17 says in [expr.call#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#4) that the implementation can choose whether to destruct the parameter object when the function returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression:

> It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression.

And in [class.temporary#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.temporary#4) it also says a temporary object (the return value object) is destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

Then if the implementation chooses to destruct parameter objects at the end of the enclosing full-expresion, which will destruct first, according to C++ standard?

Comment: Does this answer [\[class.temporary #8\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#8) ?  _"...The destruction of a temporary whose lifetime is not extended beyond the full-expression in which it was created is sequenced before the destruction of every temporary which is constructed earlier in the same full-expression...."_

Comment: I think it's not. This sentence defines the order of the destruction of **temporary objects** is the reverse of the order of the construction of them. But parameters of functions are not temporary objects.

Comment: Parameters passed by value are temporary objects created in the context of the caller.  References parameters are not objects themselves and may or may not be bound to temporaries (depends on the type of the reference)  ... off to find a standard reference.

Comment: @RichardCritten _Parameters passed by value are temporary objects… off to find a standard reference_ Would be nice to see, considering https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.temporary#1.sentence-1

Comment: I think «Temporary objects are destroyed **as the last step**» means that parameters are destroyed before temporary objects

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I may be wrong, but isn't calling a function with a by-value parameter  *implicitly* converting a prvalue (the source) into an xvalue (the copy)? And prvalue -> xvalue conversion is one of the cases cited by the Standard as creating a temporary object.

Comment: @AdrianMole plz show an example, and point at an xvalue there

Comment: I believe this is [CWG 1880](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1880). Before CWG 1880's resolution it was formally as stated by @LanguageLawyer, although with implementation divergence, however after it's resolution I would argue that it is _unspecified_. The note about temporary objects being destroyed last was present before the resolution of CWG 1880.

Comment: It is better to avoid expectations for proper destruction order in such cases. If something needs more thinking and consulting with standards, books, and manuals then better implement the algorithm in different way. Otherwise it is risk for bugs. Or maybe you write book or develop C++ compiler.

Answer (score 4):

[CWG 1880](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1880) highlighted the if not under-, at least hard-to-interpret-specification of precise details regarding destruction of function parameters compared to temporaries, describing particularly that current implementations seem to treat the two of them alike, even if the standard, albeit arguably vaguely, specifies that destruction of function parameters should precede destruction of temporaries [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### 1880. When are parameter objects destroyed?
>
> [...]
>
> According to 7.6.1.3 [expr.call] paragraph 4,
>
> > The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns. The initialization and destruction of each parameter
> > occurs within the context of the calling function.
>
> **This presumably means that the destruction of the parameter object occurs before the end of the full-expression, unlike temporaries. This
> is not what current implementations do, however.** It is not clear
> that a change to treat parameter objects like temporaries, to match
> existing practice, would be an improvement, however, as it would
> result in ABI breakage for implementations that destroy parameters in
> the called function. [...]
>
> **Notes from the June, 2014 meeting:**
>
> WG decided to make it **unspecified whether parameter objects are destroyed immediately following the call or at the end of the
> full-expression to which the call belongs.** This approach also
> resolves issue 1935.

Thus:

> What's the order of destruction of function parameters and return values?

As of resolution of CWG 1880, it is very like unspecified. Particularly, whilst resolution of CWG 1880 resulted in the addition of the section quoted by the OP

> It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression.

the potentially discriminatory note of [class.temporary]

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

was present already before the resolution of CWG 1880, e.g. in [N4140/[class.temporary]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.temporary#3). Whilst the latter could arguably be used to claim that temporaries should destroy after function parameters, even under the standard's leeway for both categories to destroy "at the end of the enclosing full-expression" (where the claim would be that "last step" trumps "at the end"), I would not rely on this brittle interpretation to be guaranteed to hold in any actual implementation.

Comment: You are a true attorney of the C++ standard. Please allow me to humbly add a few words here. Even if "last step" trumps "at the end", it still cannot win because "evaluating the full-expression" has to happen before "the end of the full-expression". :)

Answer (score -5):

I think the answer depends on how the compiler implements the standard. And the answer does not matter. From the perspective of coding, a function parameter does not exist outside the function. In other words, function parameters are irrelevant to the enclosing expression other than the function call.

[ADDED]
I don't understand why this answer gets negative votes.
From the links quoted in the posting, the standard clearly states that the destruction time of function parameters is decided by implementation. And the standard doesn't involve order question between function parameter and temporary object.

Comment: The question is tagged `language-lawyer` which means that it is asking specifically about what the standard has to say, irregardless of the practical relevance (and it may be relevant in certain special situations). "_depends on how the compiler implements the standard_" seems to imply that the sequencing is _implementation-defined_ or _indeterminate_, but that needs to be argued with reference to the standard.

Comment: "It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression." You are right, it is implementation-defined or indeterminate. And I don't think a standard lets implementation choose and decides how to implement for one of choices at the same time.

Comment: The question here is not about the implementation-definedness of the "_or_" decision in the quoted sentence, but about when exactly "_at the end of the enclosing full-expression_" for the purpose of this sentence is with respect to other evaluations happening at the end of the full-expression, i.e. destruction of temporary objects created in the full-expression.

Comment: The posting question is "which will destruct first, according to C++ standard?". Unless a standard clearly states, the answer is "implementation-defined". By the way, "a function parameter does not exist outside the function" is also to obey the standard, not only a "practical relevance".

Comment: If the standard does not specify more precisely how the object destructions at the end of the full-expression are sequenced, then they are unsequenced (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.execution-10.sentence-1), which is different from their sequencing being implementation-defined or indeterminate. Comments under the question also give good reason to assume that there is an implied concrete sequencing ("_Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step_"). Function parameters can for some implementations exist (and be used) until the end of the full-expression as your quote is stating.

Comment: "Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression". This statement does not restrict how implementation do for function parameters.